# Filling char pointer correctly

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I have a char pointer:

```
char* s = new char[150];
```

Now how do i fill it? This:

```
s="abcdef";
```

Gives warning about deprecation of conversion between string literal and `char*`, but generally works.

This:

```
char* s = new[150]("abcdef");
```

Does not work, gives an error.

How to do this properly? Note that I want the memory allocation to have 150*sizeof(char) bytes and contain "abcdef". I know about malloc, but is it possible to do with new?

Its for an assignment where i cant use the standard library.

Comment: Turn to the page in your book about C strings and `strcpy`, then abandon this approach and use `std::string`.

Comment: I know about std::string, but can't use it.

Comment: Why can't you use it?

Comment: What do you think would be the difference if you used `malloc`?

Comment: Its an assignment in which i cant use the standard library.

Comment: No difference, im just wondering if theres a way to do it with new.

Comment: @user74200 Library restrictions should be mentioned in the question. If you're not allowed the standard library, you're going to have to write your own string copying function (which is a very common homework exercise...).

Comment: @user74200 *I know about std::string, but can't use it* -- `std::string` has been a part of standard C++ for 21 years now.  That is an entire generation.  By not using it, all you're learning is how to write unsafe C++ code.

Comment: `s="abcdef";` simply leaks the memory you allocated on the other line by reassigning the pointer. (And it's not supposed to compile since C++11 due to the const difference.)

Comment: If it's an assignment then you have been surely given sufficient course material to accomplish the task and, if not, then you should discuss it with your teacher.

Comment: You might get more helpful answers if you said what your assignment *is* rather than asking about the problems with your proposed solution. (See ["The 'XY' problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Answer (score 7):

This sequence of statements

```
char* s = new char[150];
s="abcdef";
```

results in a memory leak because at first a memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `s` and then the pointer was reassigned with the address of the string literal `"abcdef"`. And moreover string literals in C++ (opposite to C) have types of constant character arrays.

If you allocated a memory for a string then you should copy a string in the memory either by using the C standard function `strcpy` or C standard function `strncpy`.

For example

```
char* s = new char[150];
std::strcpy( s, "abcdef" );
```

Or

```
const size_t N = 150;
char* s = new char[N];
std::strncpy( s, "abcdef", N );
s[N-1] = '\0';
```

Or even the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 150;
    char *s = new char[N]{ '\0' };

    std::strncpy( s, "abcdef", N - 1 );

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    delete []s;
}
```

In any case it is better just to use the standard class `std::string`.

```
std::string s( "abcdef" );
```

or for example

```
std::string s;
s.assign( "abcdef" );
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic procedure for creating a memory area for a string and then filling it without using the Standard Library in C++ is as follows:

- create the appropriate sized memory area with `new`
- use a loop to copy characters from a string into the new area

So the source code would look like:

```
// function to copy a zero terminated char string to a new char string.
// loop requires a zero terminated char string as the source.
char *strcpyX (char *dest, const char *source)
{
    char *destSave = dest;   // save copy of the destination address to return

    while (*dest++ = *source++);   // copy characters up to and including zero terminator.

    return destSave;  // return destination pointer per standard library strcpy()
}


// somewhere in your code

char *s1 = new char [150];

strcpyX (s1, "abcdef");
```

Comment: What's the difference between your `strcpyX` and the library function `std::strcpy`?  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The library version, `strcpy()`, may be optimized for the target platform; your's isn't.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews if you read the comments, this is what the post is asking for, a replacement for the standard `strcpy()`. I know the Standard Library is optimized and blah blah. That is not what the post is about. It appears to be a class assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Given a character array:

```
char * s = new char [256];
```

Here's how to fill the **pointer**:

```
std::fill(&s, &s + sizeof(s), 0);
```

Here's how to **fill** the **array**:

```
std::fill(s, s+256, '\0');
```

Here's how to **assign** or **copy text** into the **array**:

```
std::strcpy(s, "Hello");
```

You could also use `std::copy`:

```
static const char text[] = "World";
std::copy(text, text + sizeof(text), s);
```

Remember that a pointer, array and C-Style string are different concepts and objects.

**Edit 1: Prefer `std::string`**
In C++, prefer to use `std::string` for text rather than character arrays.

```
std::string s;
s = "abcdef";
std::cout << s << "\n";
```

Comment: See also: `strcat`, `strchr`, `strncpy` and `strncat`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've allocated the memory for this string, you could use [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) to populate it:

```
strcpy(s, "abcdef");
```

Comment: `strncpy` is often promoted as a safer `strcpy` but it sucks for copying c strings too. It doesn't guarantee null termination in case your array is too small. It also fills the rest of the array (the remaining space after the copy) with additional null terminators, which can be a big deal for large buffers. It does guard against buffer overflow but there are other ways of preventing overflows. In my opinion, it's best to avoid the whole family of functions.